# LED Blinker Duty Cycle

Tags: led

I am working with a simple LED flasher circuit multi vibrator I think..  Normally alternates on off between two LEDs..

My question is how to change the duty cycle to get different on/off times for each LED..  So instead of 1 on the other off you would have 1 on/off then the other on/off, and repeat.

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of your schematic?

Comment: [IMG]http://media.gibsontron.com/VMK102.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: A detailed description of your circuit is available on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Astable_multivibrator

Answer (score 1):

This multivibrator circuit of yours has only two states.  In order to get what you ask for, you need more states.  You likely will have to build it using several monostable multvibrators, and have each one trigger the next, in a loop.

Edit: Since you posted a photo, I see it is a purchased item.  Nonetheless, you can modify it to be monostable, and you can buy several boards to achieve your goal.

The standard answer is to use a microcontroller to do this instead, but I generally believe in answering the original question and letting you decide.

Details:
With this two transistor circuit, there are three ways to wire it:

- Bistable: Whichever light is on, stays on. You have to input something (like push a switch) to make the other light come on instead.  Then it stays that way. It can be flipped the other way with another switch. This behavior is like the switch that turns on the lights in the room.
- Monostable: Using a switch, you can "kick" it to the other state, where it sits for a given time, then flips back to where it was, and stays that way.  This is comparable to a 3-minute egg timer.
- Astable: It stays in one state for a time, then flips to the other.  The other state is timed, and flips back to the first state.  It never stops.  This is commonly called a "flasher".

In this circuit, either the left transistor is on, or the right one is.  When the left side turns off, the right side turns on.  The corresponding LED's indicate this.  It's really flashing one LED, and the second one can be added, but it will always be in the opposite state from the first.  These things happen together, so it isn't possible to have both off at the same time.  That would require third state--and more parts.

Let's say you could build a three-state circuit.  You'd have these states:

1. Left LED on, right LED off.
2. Right LED on, left LED off.
3. Both LED's off.

Question: When both lights are off, which one is going to come on next?  Your desired circuit has two places where one of the LED's go off without the other coming on. So, really, you need *four* states to produce this effect:

1. Left LED on, right LED off.
2. Both LED's off, with right one next.
3. Right LED on, left LED off.
4. Both LED's off, with left one next.

You can use a 555 in place of the multivibrator.  And it can be wired to be astable, bistable or monostable.  But,  you still would need four of them. Both kinds of circuits can provide a pulse to trigger the next circuit, and both have an input where the trigger can be fed in.

I suggest looking at the diagram in the Wikipedia article on multivibrators (or maybe you got a schematic with the board?), and find all the like parts on your board.  If you didn't get a schematic, you should try to draw one.

Comment: Thanks for that answer..  When you refer to modding it to be monostable do you mean it would essentially control only one LED?  It would be very helpful to know how to do that..  Then I could just use two and sync would not be an issue..  As for the original alternating on/off would a 555 chip be able to do that?  If not could you recommend one?   Thanks very much for the help...  btw:  why when I press enter does this page think I want to "save edits" instead of just a carriage return?

Comment: The comments box does not accept empty lines the way the message posting does.  That's just how they did it.  So, 'Enter' posts the comment.

Comment: Yes, if you want two unsynchronized flashing lights, just get two boards and cover over the right hand light on each.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes the 'states' thing clearer..  I guess I would like to just deal with a simple single LED circuit that flashes 1 LED.. But I guess then ON would be 1 state, OFF would be another but then there is the % time OFF vs ON..and then the total cycle time..(another state?) I'd like to work on something like this first. I thought I had seen people using a single 555 and yet get all these crazy effects..  Just to get an LED to turn ON and OFF seems quite complex yet they sell blinking LEDs..strange..

Comment: @Jim: The product you show doesn't use any 555s though, just a simple R-C timing circuit.

Comment: Yes I know there is no 555 there..  I am just trying to gather info so I know what the IC can do..  Right now I would just like to learn how to build and understand better how a single LED flasher with variable duty cycle works, etc that doesn't use two LEDs where one needs to be covered.  Thanks!

Comment: You do have that board, right?  Those two adjustable resistors at the top will let you vary the timing.  You have what you need already...for a single LED, anyway.

Comment: I don't think that circuit is it..it always powers 1 LED..so not really what I need, but I do appreciate all the help.  I need to first better understand how these work.  I get parts of it but I know I don't know enough yet. What I actually need is a dedicated single LED controller to start. I want to start with a very simple dedicated circuit that flashes 1 LED.  Then I want to move on to a modified version of something like this: (I don't even know what the 10n device is----> http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/FlasherCircuits/imagesP83/LedFlasher.gif

Comment: A 1-LED flasher is going to be the same circuit, with one LED missing. I purposely didn't say "remove the second LED" because I didn't want to make it look like it was a different circuit.  Note that the one you linked to has about as many parts as the one you started with above.  You can find ones with 1 transistor, but they don't let you set the on-time.  You get a quick flash like a strobe.

Comment: As for the "flashing LED"--they use a microcontroller chip, and the whole thing fits right on the die inside the LED!  I have "flickering candles" and they are made the same way--no other parts besides the LED and a battery.

Comment: Well that circuit is powering 1 LED all the time. If you remove 1 LED the circuit no longer flashes the remaining LED. I tried replacing the missing LED with a resistor and that worked but then as far as I can tell this means a constant draw on the circuit--not very efficient and does not do a good strobe effect lighting the LED brightly..  The last flasher circuit I posted on 'talking electronics' appears very efficient while it does not constantly draw current and maximizes a strobe effect. But the schematic is different from what I am used to and I don't fully understand it.

Comment: That's correct, the LED is in series with the transistor.  You can replace the LED with a much higher resistor to "save power".  Now then, you never told us what you wanted to do. You never mentioned you wanted a strobe.  So, yes; those strobe circuits are different.  They store a charge in a capacitor and then dump it through the LED all at once.  Different than a typical "flasher"

Answer (score 1):

"1 on/off then the other on/off, and repeat" can be summarized in a table

```
A | B
--+--
1 | 0
0 | 0
0 | 1
0 | 0
```

I would bring this about with some simple digital logic, in which the original is retained as a clock generator.

One way to do cycle through these four states would be to have two-bit counter, which is edge triggered. On each rising edge of the clock, it increments: 00, 01, 10, 11.

The values of this counter can then be filtered through some combinatorial logic to generate the A and B signals. For LED A, what is that logic?

```
A | C1 C0 (counter)
--+-------
1 |  0  0
0 |  0  1
0 |  1  0
0 |  1  1
```

Hey look, A is the NOR truth table. A is 1 only when the counter is 0: neither bit 1 NOR bit 2 are set. So a simple NOR gate over the two bit counter gives you the signal for LED A.

How about B?

```
A B | C1 C0 (counter)
----+-------
1 0 |  0  0
0 0 |  0  1
0 1 |  1  0
0 0 |  1  1
```

The function for B is "C1 and not C0". With DeMorgan's Law we can turn this into nor: (not C1) NOR C0:   invert both inputs, change AND to OR, and negate the whole thing. (Negated OR is NOR).  E.g. A and B means (not A) nor (not B): neither a can be false, nor a can be false.

A single NOR gate can also be used to make an inverter (just tie the inputs together) so you can cob together this combinatorial logic with three NOR gates which can be easily found on one TTL or CMOS chip.

Another chip will give you a four bit counter. Just supply a clock and the chip has outputs for the four bits. With a simple DPDT switch you can toggle between two pairs of counter bits for two different speeds at the same clock rate. Say, bits 0-1 for fast, or bits 2-3 for 1/4 speed.

Here is another idea: use all four bits of a four bit counter to give yourself 16 states. Decode these states into 16 discrete lines with a 4x16 decoder (like a 74154). Then, configure which LED's are turned on in which states using two rows of 16 DIP switches: one for LED A and one for B. Each switch connects the given LED to the given line.

This is like being able to sequence a repeating measure of 16th notes in 4/4 time: quite decent flexibility.